# All lines starting ABC, find a any character in position range X-Y and replace with 123

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I need to find all lines that begin with 'TAG' and replace whatever is in position 52-59 (could be characters, could be empty spaces) and replace with the word 'NENTRIES'.

Some example lines in file:

```
TTL0000021900000003W-000101628   SIGNED SEALED DELIVERED I'M YOURS
PER000002190000000400033189687010CA000000000000001250              00000000000
TAG00000219000000056669010790     NA             NA0000000000033189687WONDER
TAG00000219000000066669010790     NA             NA        00033189687WONDER
TAG00000219000000076669010790     NA             NA        00033189687WONDER
PER000002190000000800077637832010CA000000000000001250              00000000000
TAG00000219000000096669010789     NA             NA        00077637832WRIGHT
TAG00000219000000106669346202     NA             NA        00077637832WRIGHT
TTL0000022000000011W-000102057   TAKE IT EASY
```

OUTPUT:

```
TTL0000021900000003W-000101628   SIGNED SEALED DELIVERED I'M YOURS
PER000002190000000400033189687010CA000000000000001250              00000000000
TAG00000219000000056669010790     NA             NANENTRIES00033189687WONDER
TAG00000219000000066669010790     NA             NANENTRIES00033189687WONDER
TAG00000219000000076669010790     NA             NANENTRIES00033189687WONDER
PER000002190000000800077637832010CA000000000000001250              00000000000
TAG00000219000000096669010789     NA             NANENTRIES00077637832WRIGHT
TAG00000219000000106669346202     NA             NANENTRIES00077637832WRIGHT
TTL0000022000000011W-000102057   TAKE IT EASY
```

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

regex: `(TAG.{48}).{8}`

replace: `$1NENTRIES`

NOTES:

- `(TAG.{48})` captures the litteral "TAG" and 48 following characters
- `$1` in the replacement is the group captured by `(TAG.{48})`

[exemple of the regex in Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SaIOXB/1)

**EDIT:** if you want to use numbers after the `$1`, use `${1}`, or else if you use `$10` the regex wants to use the tenth match where it doesn't exist:

regex: `(TAG.{48}).{8}`

replace: `${1}00000000`

Comment: If I wanted to replace it with '00000000', how would I do that? $100000000 replaces the entire string up to the desired position. Thanks.

Comment: @Moe updated the answer, you can use `${1}00000000`